# Duplicate Permission AndroidManifest.xml with React Native

Tags: react-native

Is it ok to have duplicate permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file?

I am trying to add in react-native-webrtc into my react-native project which requires me to add in some permissions. The initial AndroidManifest.xml file already have a list of permissions which some will be duplicated if I add in the permissions required by react-native-webrtc. Since, im on this question, does the same goes for ios?

**REQUIRED TO ADD IN BY REACT-NATIVE-WEBRTC**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**ORIGINAL**

```
 <!-- These are required permissions to make the app run -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.bulbtech.hendrysocket.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <!-- ADD PERMISSIONS HERE -->

  <!-- BEGIN OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not duplicate permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file and if you duplicate the permission then your code gets crashed and some goes for ios

Comment: Thanks for d guidance 

Comment: @HendryLim no problem ask me if you have any problem